# Como fazer o Hibernate Search ordenar o resultado de uma busca?

Tags: java, hibernate, java-ee

Tenho uma **busca indexada** com o [Hibernate Search](http://hibernate.org/search/) mas não consigo fazer com que o Hibernate Search **ordene o resultado da busca pela ordem de uma determinada coluna**, como por exemplo a coluna nome.

Mas existe **uma peculiaridade**. Quando a busca é feito utilizando algum termo, o resultado então é ordenado perfeitamente por ordem alfabética. No entanto, se eu não colocar nenhum termo na busca (quero que retorne todos os resultados), então o Hibernate Search já não ordena mais nada.

Veja os códigos relativos as duas buscas:

### Usando um filtro (funciona)

Abaixo está o meu método que busca filtrando através de um termo. **Essa busca funciona perfeitamente e ordena certinho pelo nome (alfabeticamente)**.

```
public List<Colaborador> filtrar(String termo) throws DAOException {
    try {
        FullTextEntityManager fullTextEm = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(this.entityManager);
        QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEm.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Colaborador.class).get();
        Query query = qb.keyword().onFields("nome", "email", "usuario").matching(termo).createQuery();
        FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEm.createFullTextQuery(query);

        // Ordenação ocorre corretamente aqui!
        Sort sortField = new Sort(new SortField("nome", SortField.STRING));

        fullTextQuery.setSort(sortField);
        return fullTextQuery.getResultList();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Erro ao filtrar colaboradores com termo: " + termo, e);
        throw new DAOException(e);
    }
}
```

### Trazendo todos os registros (não funciona a ordenação)

Abaixo está um método muito similar ao que postei acima, no entanto o método abaixo apenas não ordena corretamente os registros que são retornados pelo Hibernate Search. Repare que é a mesma entidade (`Colaborador.class`) e mesmo assim a ordem pelo nome não funciona corretamente.

```
public List<Colaborador> listarColaboradores() throws DAOException {
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEm = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(this.entityManager);
    QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEm.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Colaborador.class).get();
    FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = fullTextEm.createFullTextQuery(qb.all().createQuery());

    // A mágica deveria ser feita aqui!
    Sort sortField = new Sort(new SortField("nome", SortField.STRING));

    fullTextQuery.setSort(sortField);
    return fullTextQuery.getResultList();
}
```

Alguém já passou por isso? Sabe o que pode estar acontecedo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema estava na minha entidade.

```
@Entity
@Indexed
@Table(name = "my_view")
public class Colaborador implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 244555315052436669L;

    @Id
    @Field(store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Field(store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "name", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String nome;

    @Field(store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "email", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String email;

    @Field(store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
    @Column(name = "user", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String usuario;

    //Getters e Setters omitidos
}
```

Vejam que o atributo `private String nome;`, na qual eu quero ordenar minha busca, está anotado da seguinte maneira:

```
@Field(store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
@Column(name = "nome", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private String nome;
```

Fazendo pesquisas e mais pesquisas, achei [**um trecho na documentação do Hibernate Search**](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.0/reference/en-US/html_single/) que diz o seguinte:

> Fields used for sorting must not be analyzed.

Então alterei o mapeamento da minha entidade para:

```
@Field(store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO)
@Column(name = "nome", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private String nome;
```

E fui testar minha aplicação. Para minha surpresa **a ordenação funcionou, mas o filtro pelo atributo name, parou de funcionar**. Ou seja, arrumei uma coisa e quebrei outra. E voltei as minhas pesquisas e acabei na documentação do Hibernate Search novamente.

Descobri que um mesmo atributo pode ser mapeado duas vezes para o Hibernate Search. Então você pode, em um mapeamento usar o `Analyze.YES` e rodar a query em cima desse mapeamento e um segundo mapeamento com `Analyze.NO` para fazer a ordenação. Parece complicado? Veja o código:

```
@Fields({
    @Field(name = "nome_ordem", store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO),
    @Field(name = "nome", store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES)
})
@Column(name = "nome", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private String nome;
```

Reparem que eu crio dois índices para um mesmo atributo. Um é usado como campo de filtro e o outro como ordenação. Fazendo dessa forma, consigo então buscar por esse atributo e também ordena-lo!